# SQL query with CUBE err

Tags: sql, database, group-by, hive, sum

for example, i have a table ORDERS

ORDERS{o_orderkey, o_custkey, o_orderstatus, o_totalprice, o_orderdate, o_orderpriority, o_clerk...blah blah...}

i tried

```
SELECT o_orderkey, o_orderdate, sum(o_totalprice)
FROM orders
GROUP BY CUBE (o_orderkey, o_orderdate)
ORDER BY o_orderkey, o_orderdate;
```

But it gives me error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:5 cannot recognize input near 'CUBE' '(' 'o_orderkey' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)

---

So i figured out an answer to my top part of the question, now i have a second table

LINEITEM{ l_orderkey, l_suppkey and ...blah blah...}

The first table links to this LINEITEM table via the ***orderkey*** field,

so i want to find the total number of parts ordered by these 2 clerks(o_clerk)

o_clerk='Clerk#000000522' OR o_clerk='Clerk#000000154' per

orderdate(o_orderdate), per suppkey(l_suppkey).

This is my working but i am not sure if it is correct:

```
SELECT o_clerk, o_orderdate, l.l_suppkey, sum(l.l_quantity) as TotalParts
FROM orders as o, lineitem as l
WHERE o.o_orderkey = l.l_orderkey
AND o.o_clerk='Clerk#000000522' OR o.o_clerk='Clerk#000000154'
GROUP BY o_clerk, o_orderdate, l.l_suppkey WITH CUBE
ORDER BY o_orderdate, l.l_suppkey;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hive, you would phrase this as:

```
SELECT o_orderkey, o_orderdate, sum(o_totalprice)
FROM orders
GROUP BY o_orderkey, o_orderdate CUBE
ORDER BY o_orderkey, o_orderdate;
```

Comment: yes i realized i had to GROUP BY o_orderkey, o_orderdate WITH CUBE;